# LSD-SLAM NOROS on Windows. No PointCloud

Tags: c++, git, github, slam

Has anyone tried building this git repository (https://github.com/aivijay/lsd_slam_noros) which lets you build a LSD-Slam program on Windows that's independent of ROS. Problem is that I was able to build it but there's no PointCloud generated when I do. Based on people's comments on the repository it seems to work for them (tried commenting but to no reply). Has anyone else used it?

Comment: So the reason is that it is running well but the point cloud viewer isn't ported over XD. So the point cloud is being generated just you can't see it

Comment: Yeah realised this so using PCL but isn't adapting to the moving camera. Any tips?